# Accessing login credentials and show them on the drawer component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app in which i want to show the login credentials like email,name on the custom drawer component. I have been able to access the details when i console the info but not been able to show them in the drawer.

```js
const customDrawerContentComponent = async (props) => {
      
      let userInfo = {};

      try {
       await AsyncStorage.getItem('userInfo')
        .then(function (value) {
          return Object.assign(userInfo, JSON.parse(value))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
      
        console.log(userInfo)
     }
```

when i do this, i get the details. But when i try to show the details on the drawer like (userInfo.name) it shows blank.

[the error from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6mKO.png)

How can i show these details on the custom drawer component?

Comment: The warning your're getting is because your not handling your promise. You need to resolve your promise properly. Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE to learn more. You would need to return userInfo to use it anywhere else.

Comment: can you show me how can i return userInfo according to the above code

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing the syntax of Async/Await and standard promises. You can assign the value of your await to a variable and then iterate through the result to render your content, like so:

```
const customDrawerContentComponent = async (props) => {
    try {
        const userInfo = await AsyncStore.getItem('userInfo');
        console.log(userInfo);
        return (
            <div>
                {/* Don't know what userInfo is, but according to your error it looks like it's an array. */}
                {userInfo.map(item => (
                    <p>item</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Oops, there was an error: ', e);
        return (
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(e)}
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Take a look at the Async/Await documentation to see how it differs from resolving a normal promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Just changing the functional component to class based component solved my promise handling problem.